# Format of video url

Tags: android, url, video, video-streaming, progressive-download

I have a video url (either progressive download or streaming) and I want to determine its format to check if it complies with Android's [supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). How can I check this? Is it enough if it works on the emulator?

(as far as I understand testing it on a device is not a warranty since some Android devices might support formats that others do not)

Comment: Did you use Progress Download successfully? I am [on stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277530/android-videoview-and-progressive-download). Would you like to give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

`Testing it on device is not a warranty` as you said. I agree. Documentation itself suggests us to test on as many different devices as possible, and this is something we can only learn through experience.

As of now I haven't come across a method in `MediaPlayer`/`VideoView` which could extract meta information of Videos.

can you have a server side script which tells you the video's details?