# Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device in Http streaming android

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, android-videoview, http-streaming

I **can stream some videos from URL (server) successfully,**

But **the others (my video up to my server) is not**.

You can see both in my code **(Working/Not working)**
I'm on stuck with this problem.
**"Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device"**

The following code :

```
String url = null;
    //      url = "rtsp://v5.cache5.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmC00ZlwwIDOxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"; // Working
    //      url = "http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp"; // Working
    url = "http://www.ooklnet.com/files/381/381489/video.mp4"; // Working
    //      url = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"; // Working
    //      url = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80419/santa.mp4"; // Working

    //      url = "http://trekvn.hostoi.com/encode_normal.mp4"; // Not Working
    //      url = "http://trekvn.hostoi.com/output_encode_mp4_box.mp4"; // Not Working
    //      url = "http://www.ourserversite.com:14556/ingCloud/users/400010001/mp4_320p/e8d8535852a98c949640c5d618ac23d320131022174507.mp4"; // Not Working
    //      url = "http://trekvn.hostoi.com/mpeg_2_ts.ts"; // Not Working

    videoviewer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));

    videoviewer.requestFocus();
    videoviewer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    videoviewer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    videoviewer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
           videoviewer.start()'
}
```

All of these video can play good on the site,
have format *.mp4 (mpeg-4 part 10), Video : .H264, Audio : aac.

Please tell me why,
and how to fix it.

p/s : Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" - 2.2.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is the issue that many people met**, ensure you understand following content to fix the issue.

Through my experience and the answer in this [Sorry, this video cannot be played - streaming mp4 to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012494/sorry-this-video-cannot-be-played-streaming-mp4-to-android)

Finally, I found the reason and the solution:

*- Reason :* Almost the ***.mp4 file was produced for developing focus on iOS**, and have the **encoding : H264 Main**. While **Android side can only stream & play the files have the encoding : [H264 Baseline](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).**

*- Solution :* We need **convert from the encoding H264 Main to H264 Baseline** (**guaranteed enabled Web Optimized** (move -moov atom before -mdat) feature)

*- Bugs :*

- **Sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device**.
- **Sorry, this video can not be played**.

[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) tool is the easiest and cheapest way to complete it.

Thanks,

*p/s : But if you use this method, you need upload your video to the server for testing.*