# How to intent to system media application in android

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player, media, intentfilter

**How to intent to system media application?**

Because I want to play the video in my application by using system media application.

I trying the following code, but not successfully.

```
    url = "http://www.ooklnet.com/files/381/381489/video.mp4";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But when i trying the following code, it is successfull,

```
    url = "http://www.ooklnet.com/files/381/381489/video.mp4";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
```

However, It needs me to open two steps:

- First step is show the dialog (Android System & Browser) to choose.
- Second step : when I choose Android System, it shows the applications can play this video.

I want to **press "Play" button, it will run by using system media application**,

Please tell me how,

**UPDATE** after receive the answer from CommonWare :

I can use the following code **to intent exactly the system media app** guy.

```
// String type = "audio/mpeg4-generic"; // It works for only Mobo Player
String type = "video/mp4"; // It works for all video application

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), type);
startActivity(intent);
```

My device has existed third media application **(Mobo Player, MX Player and Video)**, 
The **Video application is the system media app**, so we can not uninstall it in the **Settings**.

p/s : I use Android version 2.2.1,

Thanks,

Comment: what is the error, log cat please?

Comment: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER,android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC] dat=http://www.ooklnet.com/files/381/381489/video.mp4 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I trying the following code, but not successfully.

There is no activity on your system that both can play a video and is a music player.

> First step is show the dialog (Android System & Browser) to choose.

The user can display this video in whatever application they want.

> Second step : when I choose Android System, it shows the applications can play this video.

Presumably, that is occurring sometime after the URL has been downloaded or something. You might try using `setDataAndType()`, supplying the proper MIME type, to streamline this a bit.

> I want to press "Play" button, it will run by using system media application,

There is no "system media application". A device may have zero, one, or several applications capable of playing a video from a URL. Those applications can be pre-installed or installed by the user. When you request to play a video using `ACTION_VIEW`, the OS and the user will decide which application will play the video.

Comment: Really thanks for your good answer, I totally understand you and updated the question. But I got another problem. [Can you tell me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587880/some-video-urls-play-good-some-not-in-http-streaming-android), please