# Android Sorry, this video cannot be played

Tags: android, video, video-player

I'm using VideoPlayer in my app. It play everything fine but when I want to scroll on the media player's bar, usually it gives me the error : Sorry, this video cannot be played. and I have to restart the video to watch it again. All I found is if I stop the video and scroll the bar it will be fine. I just wonder how can I fix this problem ? how can I access to media player's bar. Hens I can pause the video onClick. My code:

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(
                rootView.getContext());
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(passVideo.file_link);

        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                video.requestFocus();
                video.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Many people get this error like you,

> Bugs :
>
> > Sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device.
> >
> > Sorry, this video can not be played.

You can find out at [**Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device in Http streaming android**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587880/sorry-this-video-is-not-valid-for-streaming-to-this-device-in-http-streaming-an/19632271#19632271)

Thanks,