# How to integrate the Vitamio library in my project android?

Tags: android, eclipse, vitamio

I **need to play .avi .mov and .wmv files** in my android application. 
I'm doing tests in eclipse emulator but I can not play these files, so I have not managed to integrate the library into my project. I have done the following steps:

- Create a project in Eclipse with package VitamioBundle-4.2.1 library.
- Add the aggregate in the previous step to my Android project library, by: Properties / Android / Library / Add ...
- Add 'InitActivity' class to AndroidManifest.xml

I have also created a new project to test the example that comes with the library, called 'VitamioListActivity' but do not get to play files of these formats.

Please appreciate someone show me the steps to play these files on a android application. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can anyone help me? It`s important, please.

Answer (score 0):

Many people get this error like you,

Bugs :

```
Sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device.
Sorry, this video can not be played.
```

You can find out at [Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device in Http streaming android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587880/sorry-this-video-is-not-valid-for-streaming-to-this-device-in-http-streaming-an/19632271#19632271)

Thanks,

Comment: I think that you don´t have understood my question ... I can play mp4 files in my Android app, but I can´t play mov, avi or wmv files! 
And your response is about problems with H.264 encoding in mp4 files (if I have understood well) ...